# Exercise of derivation under the integral sign

Tags: real-analysis

How do I solve the following exercise?

Find $$\frac{\partial }{\partial x}f\left ( x,y \right ),\ \frac{\partial }{\partial y}f\left ( x,y \right ), \text{ where }\ f\left ( x,y \right )=\int_{x^{2}y}^{y^{3}+xy+x^{2}}g\left ( t \right )dt$$

In which book I can find the demonstration in general form of the calculation of the partial derivatives functions $$f\left ( x,y \right )=\int_{u\left ( x,y \right )}^{h\left ( x,y \right )}g\left ( t \right )\ dt\ ?$$

thanks for your help

Comment: Leibniz's rule: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Answer (score 1):

This is an exercise in the fundamental theorem of calculus, and in particular the statement that
$$ \frac{d}{dx} \int_0^{a(x)} g(t) dt = g(a(x)) a'(x).$$
For instance,
$$ \frac{d}{dx} \int_0^{y^3 + xy + x^2} f(t) dt = f(y^3 + xy + x^2) \cdot (y + 2x).$$
You can do the same for the lower-bounds and for the derivative with respect to $y$.

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact that 
$$\int_{f(x)}^{g(x)} h(t)\, dt = \int_0^{g(x)}h(t)\, dt - \int_0^{f(x)}
h(t)\, dt,$$
the fundamental theorem of calculus, and the chain rule in concert.